# Kubernetes API get service endpoint IP when available

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform

I have a process where I use a Kubernetes client to build a deployment and a service. This process works fine but I have to wait some time for google to assign it an external IP. I cant seem to find anything in googles docs about a possible event emitter for when this process is done. Is there a way to programmatically pass or configure a request that can be made to a REST api that could go out and retrieve the info once it its ready?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. I assume that you mean to assign a [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/#loadbalancer) type of address to your Kubernetes [service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). You can manually query the GCP API to see if your Load Balancer IP has been allocated. For example, [GET](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/addresses/get) a resource address.

You can also use the [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/addresses/) command.

[Here is](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/apis) a list of all the GCP APIs related to load balancing that you can use.